# Deprecated Embedded Jetty 7.6 using SSL

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I am trying to build an embedded jetty application which is fine so far. But if i try to use SSL it seems all methods are deprecated. I found a post here on stackoverflow where the poster solved his problem by using the SslContextFactory but if i copy those lines my ide marks the SslContextFactory as deprecated too.

What would be the proper way of solving this?

i had a look at the following similar questions but they don't seem to solve my problem:

- [Jetty SslConnector's deprecated methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220651/jetty-sslconnectors-deprecated-methods)
- [How to set up SSL on an embedded Jetty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053642/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-an-embedded-jetty)

Answer (score 0):

```
org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl.SslContextFactory
```

is deprecated in 7.6; try using

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jetty version 7.6. Here are the imports I used.

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
```

Below is some example code using the new SslContextFactory.

```
Server server = new Server();

// Encrypt the connection using a valid certificate/keystore
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory("path/keystore.jks");
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");

// Create new socket connector using the contextFactory
SslSocketConnector sslConnector = new SslSocketConnector(sslContextFactory);
sslConnector.setPort(443);

// Add the SocketConnector to the server
server.setConnectors(new Connector[] {sslConnector});
```